# CSS background image not showing when declaring doctype

Tags: html, css

When I declare the doctype in vscode for this website the background image does not show as the height is set to 0, the background image only shows in quirks mode.

The image is still accessible via the link in inspect element.

I have tried revising the code, using a different image, rearranging its position and altering the values in the stylesheet.

Any reason as to why this is happening?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hot Beans Web - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesimages/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="stylesimages/logo.png" width="400px" height="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="bgimage"></div>
        <div class="bg-text">
            <h1 style="font-size:90px">We code the future.</h1>
            <p>Providing rich, advanced and sophisticated IT solutions that will make your website shine.</p>
          </div>
        <p>asjjssj</p>
        <h1><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Hot Beans Web</a></h1>
        <button>shshs</button>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Link to Youtube</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.bgimage {
    background-image:url("homebackground.jpeg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #ac1b1b;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.bg-text {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[file paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSQam.png)

Comment: Surely the path to the image should be relative to the html document, not the css sheet. The css rules become part of the html document as if they were included in it so the relative path should be from the html document. You say you tried altering things but not what you tried?

Comment: I just realised I'm totally wrong about this. I usually have css files at the same directory level as html and always assumed the relative paths were from the html file. A quick test shows I'm wrong about that, live and learn! I'll delete the comment shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not actually test your code. Since the div with the image background is immediately closed, i.e. does not have any child (`<div class="bgimage"></div>`) and its height is set to `100%` in css, it will get a height of 0px. First, try changing that height value to `100vh` (viewport height) to see if it works. Then, if you want that image to be the background of the whole page, try moving `bgimage` class from that div to `body` element.